# If $x=\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{3^2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2015^2}$, show that $\frac{201}{403}<x<\frac{2014}{2015}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, riemann-sum

> If $$x=\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{3^2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2015^2}$$
> show that
> $$\frac{201}{403}<x<\frac{2014}{2015}$$

So, I manage to do the RH inequality using that $$x<\frac{1}{2\cdot3}+\frac{1}{3\cdot4}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2014\cdot2015}=1-\frac{1}{2015}=\frac{2014}{2015}$$ Unfortunately I can't find a way to do the LH inequality. I saw that
$$\frac{1}{2015}+\frac{1}{2015}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2015}$$ for 1005 times is equal to $\frac{201}{403}$ but I don't see why
$$x> \frac{1}{2015}+\frac{1}{2015}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2015}$$ thx!

Comment: You can also be cheeky and set $x \approx \pi^2/6 -1$, then show that $2015x < 2014$ and $403x>201$. Probably not the desired method though.

Answer (score 6):

We have the bound
$$\sum_{n=2}^{2015}\frac{1}{n^2}>\int_2^{2016}\frac{1}{x^2}dx=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2016}>\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{806}=\frac{402}{806}=\frac{201}{403}$$
by thinking about the graph of the function $y=1/x^2$ and noticing that if you draw rectangles of base length $1$ with four vertices $(n,0),(n+1,0),(n,1/n^2),(n+1,1/n^2)$ for $n=2,\dots,2015$ then the union of the resulting rectangles have an area bounded below by the integral given above.

By the way, this also works to establish the upper bound $2014/2015$.

Answer (score 6):

We have
$$\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+1} < \frac{1}{k^2} < \frac{1}{k-1} - \frac{1}{k}$$

and so (telescoping sum)

$$\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2016} < \sum_{k=2}^{2015} \frac{1}{k^2} < \frac{1}{1} - \frac{1}{2015}$$
that is
$$\frac{1007}{2016}< \sum_{k=2}^{2015} \frac{1}{k^2} < \frac{2014}{2015}$$

Now,  LHS $= \frac{2014}{4032}= \frac{201.4}{403.2}> \frac{201}{403}$ ([mediant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediant_(mathematics)))